# Is interest from US Savings Bonds subject to nonresident alien tax withholding?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, government-bonds, withholding

A person received some US Series EE Savings Bonds when he was a child.

He was always a nonresident alien for US tax purposes and he is not from a treaty country.

The Bonds matured in 2001 and has stopped accumulating interest since then.

90% of the final value of the Bonds consists of accumulated interest.

Is there a 30% tax withholding on redemption?